# How can I increment database counter after each page login or reload?

Tags: database, field, counter, increment, portal

I am developing a school portal that requires students to check their results with scratch cards. I want each scratch card to expire after being used to check result for 5 times. My MYSQL database table has the following fields:

```
id    regno  pin   serial   count
```

I want the count field to increment after a student logs in with his/her scratch card until it gets to 5.

Here is my code snippet:

```
for($counter=1; $counter<=5; $counter++){
$sql = "UPDATE `{$table}` SET `count`= '{$counter}' + 1,`time_used`='{$time}', `pin` = '{$pin}' ,`serial` = '{$serial}'  WHERE `regno` = '{$regno}'";
}
```

The count `field` increments just once and stops after multiple login attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You may just push data to your table, but configure one of the column to be auto-incremental.

So no need for counters, just do an INSERT.

If you cannot modify the db, you first have to check the latest value with a SELECT and then increment and INSERT after the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

On my understanding, assuming that the student might log in again, once the session is expired then

you can select the max value of counter from the table based on the id, regno, pin (whichever is the unique identifier)and check if the counter is less than 5.

If yes, then increment the counter and insert the value into the table and allow then multiple logins.

If the counter is equal to 5 then stops multiple login attempts.

Comment: @Jean T: But setting any of the columns to auto increment looks like a good idea, but my db is a large one with a lot of foreign key constraints imposed on many other fields from other tables, and for this reason, if I try to make the count field auto increment and assigning a primary key to it, I do have this error: 

1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
Field 

I have looked up suggestions here. I ran these:


ALTER TABLE table DROP PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE table CHANGE `count` `count` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

Comment: :I did SELECT AND UPDATE. The counter auto increments successfully after each page refresh, but I still have a challenge.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$table}` WHERE `scratch_card_pin` = '{$scratch_card_pin}' AND `scratch_card_serial` = '{$scratch_card_serial}' LIMIT 1";
  $confirm = $this>query($sql);   
    while($counter = $this->fetch_array($confirm)){
   $currentcounter = $counter['count'];
   $countervalue = "UPDATE `{$table}` SET `count` = '{$currentcounter}' + 1  WHERE `scratch_card_pin` = '{$scratch_card_pin}' AND `scratch_card_serial` = '{$scratch_card_serial}'";

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem with this function:

public function counter($pin, $serial, $regno,  $table){
global $ok;
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$table}` WHERE `pin` = '{$pin}' AND `serial` = '{$serial}' AND `regno` = '{$regno}' LIMIT 1";
        $confirm = $ok->query($sql);
        if($ok->number_of_rows($confirm) == 0){ return false;}elseif($ok->number_of_rows($confirm) == 1){
          while($counter = $ok->fetch_array($confirm)){
            $currentcounter = $counter['count'];
            $countervalue = "UPDATE `{$table}` SET `count` = '{$currentcounter}' + 1  WHERE `pin` = '{$pin}' AND `serial` = '{$serial}' AND `regno` = '{$regno}'";
            $incrementedcounter = $ok->query($countervalue);
                  if($counter['count']  <= 3){
                    return true;//"CARD IS STILL ACTIVE";
                    }
                    elseif($counter['count'] > 3)
                    {
                    return false;//"CARD HAS EXPIRED";
                    }
              }
       return $incrementedcounter;
    }
}

NB: The trick is this:
1. I used the above function to auto increment my counter in the db whenever a student logs in with a particular card pin and  serial;
2. I wrote another function that sets a field to ACTIVE OR INACTIVE depending on the value of the counter. If the $counter<= 3, the field is set to ACTIVE allowing that student to continue to login and use the card. However, if $counter > 4, the field is set to INACTIVE and the counter whose field is `count` will stop auto incrementing no mattter how many times the student may try to login using the expired card.